# Simple javascript gallery, show big image on click of each small thumbnail image

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image: this is my gallery]

```
let imagePlaceholder = document.querySelector('#defaultImage');
let onClickImage1 = document.querySelector('#onClickImage1');
let onClickImage2 = document.querySelector('#onClickImage2');
let onClickImage3 = document.querySelector('#onClickImage3');
let onClickImage4 = document.querySelector('#onClickImage4');
let onClickImage5 = document.querySelector('#onClickImage5');
let onClickImage6 = document.querySelector('#onClickImage6');
let onClickImages = document.getElementsByClassName('onClickImage');
let imagePlaceholder = document.querySelector('#defaultImage');
```

I have the above variables. `onClickImageN` (from 1 to 6) are six different images which are the bottom.
`onClickImages` is an array containing these 6 images.
`imagePlaceholder` is the image at the top.
When clicked one of the six bottom images, `imagePlaceholder.src` must be set to the `src` of the image that is clicked.

```
onClickImage1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    imagePlaceholder.src=currentPath=onClickImage1.src;
})
onClickImage2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    imagePlaceholder.src=currentPath=onClickImage2.src;
})
onClickImage3.addEventListener('click', () => {
    imagePlaceholder.src=currentPath=onClickImage3.src;
})
onClickImage4.addEventListener('click', () => {
    imagePlaceholder.src=currentPath=onClickImage4.src;
})
onClickImage5.addEventListener('click', () => {
    imagePlaceholder.src=currentPath=onClickImage5.src;
})
onClickImage6.addEventListener('click', () => {
    imagePlaceholder.src=currentPath=onClickImage6.src;
})
```

I have written the above code to achieve the desired behavior, but I feel like there is too much repetition. I tried using `for` and `forEach` loops, but wasn't able to get it working. Please help me out.

Comment: I'm confused with the click event.. are you re-appling the same image to the existing image ?

Comment: @kemicofaghost If you see in the screenshot I have attached, There is one big image at the top and six at the bottom. When clicked on one of the smaller images, the big image gets set to the one that's clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use classes instead of `id`s but it works both ways. you could replace `class` from the selector with `id`. See how it works without using the `number` in the selector. Then you can just iterate over all the "images" and add them the `click event handler`

```js
let imagePlaceholder = document.querySelector('#defaultImage');
let images = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="onClickImage"]');

images.forEach( image => {
  image.addEventListener('click', () => {
    imagePlaceholder.src = image.src;
  });
});
```

```css
#defaultImage {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
[class^="onClickImage"] {
   height: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img id="defaultImage" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff.jpg&text=default" />
<img class="onClickImage0" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff.jpg&text=default" />
<img class="onClickImage1" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff.jpg&text=1" />
<img class="onClickImage2" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff.jpg&text=2" />
<img class="onClickImage3" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff.jpg&text=3" />
<img class="onClickImage4" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff.jpg&text=4" />
<img class="onClickImage5" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff.jpg&text=5" />
<img class="onClickImage6" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff.jpg&text=6" />
<img class="onClickImage7" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000/fff.jpg&text=7" />
```